# How can I perform a $lookup on a property value in a nested array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an `articles` collection that contains an array of `comments`, and this array contains an array of `sub_comments`. Here is what it looks like:

```
let articleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String},
    comments: [{
        comment: {type: String},
        creator: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        sub_comments: [{
            comment: {type: String},
            creator: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

I'm trying to run an `aggregate` query that does a `$lookup` on the `comments.creator` and `sub_comments.creator` fields. Here's what I've tried so far, but it doesn't work:

```
this.model('Article')
    .aggregate([
        {
            $match: {_id: article_id}
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "comments.creator",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "comments.creator"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$comments.creator",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "comments.sub_comments.creator",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "comments.sub_comments.creator"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$comments.sub_comments.creator",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                title: 1,
                "comments.comment": 1,
                "comments.creator._id": 1,
                "comments.creator.name": 1,
                "comments.sub_comments.comment": 1,
                "comments.sub_comments.creator._id": 1,
                "comments.sub_comments.creator.name": 1
            }
        }
    ])
    .exec(function (err, data) {
        ...
    });
```

Here's an example of the `data` response:

```
[{
"_id": "5b7e1629d00a170018e11234",
"article": "My Article",
"comments": {
        "comment": "This is the comment.",
    "sub_comments": {},
    "creator": {
    "_id": "541g2dfeab1e470b00411234",
    "name": "John Doe"
    }
},
    ....
}]
```

Comments should be an array, not an object. This particular comment didn't have any sub-comments, but obviously, I want that to work too. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

the  `as  params` in mongodb  `$lookup` with  your query  affect  your  result .

> as    Specifies the name of the new array field to add to the input
>   documents. The new array field contains the matching documents from
>   the from collection. If the specified name already exists in the input
>   document, the existing field is overwritten.

it  will overwrite  the filed  .  not  add  to it  .
if  your  outter  is  an array  ,it will make it to Object  and  delete   the current content .
so the   second  `$lookup`  in aggregate  will not work  . in your query

if you want  to keep the current data structure intac . you can  `as  a new fieldname` and  use `$project`  to  change the format .